# SQL group by not returning row value for an aggregate column

Tags: sql, max

I was using SQL statement to bring an aggregate (MAX) for a column  and rest of the columns should come from that row. I was using group by clause but for other columns I must also use either max or min, etc. This was budget oriented project so I could not have time to do it using LINQ. (Where I could have used first or default). Anyways I believe this is strong inability of SQL language.

Again this could have done by many ways but not using simple SQL group by.

any ideas?

Comment: Please show a Minimal, Reproducible Example! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide sample code/ code that you have tried.

Comment: In addition to the previous two comments: which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I was using as back end MS Sql Server. The front end was a windows form using c#. I was building a master-detail data bound grid using SQL query. The query got involved many tables but the mix up happened because of I tried to narrow down to a row based on MAX(of a column). Due to high complexity of the query, which was divert the problem, I did not give the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit light on details but it sounds like you want to know, for some set of items, which item has the maximum of something and then what it’s other properties are.

You cannot group by all the non max columns because this breaks the group down into too small chunks to make the max work

You cannot max all the other columns because this mixes row data up

Here is a simple example:

```
Name, JobRole, StartDate
John, JuniorProgrammer, 2000-01-01
John, SeniorProgrammer, 2010-01-01
```

John was promoted to senior programmer in 2010. We want johns most recent promotion and what he does now. If we do this:

```
SELECT name, jobrole, max(startdate)
FROM emp
GROUP BY name
```

The database will complain that jobrole is not in the group by. If we add it to the group by, John will appear twice, not what we want. If instead we max(jobrole), it DOES accidentally work out ok because alphabetically, SeniorProgrmamer is higher than JuniorProgrammer

If however, John then gets a promotion again in 2019:

```
Name, JobRole, StartDate
John, JuniorProgrammer, 2000-01-01
John, SeniorProgrammer, 2010-01-01
John, ExecutiveDirector, 2019-01-01
```

This time our query is wrong:

```
SELECT name, max(jobrole), max(startdate)
FROM emp
GROUP BY name
```

Hi he row data will be mixed up: the date will be 2019 but the job will still be seniorprogrammer because it’s alphabetically the maximum value

Instead we have to find the max for the person and then join it back to find the rest of the data:

```
SELECT name, jobrole, startdate
FROM
  emp
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT name, max(startdate) d
    FROM emp
    GROUP BY name 
  )findmax
  ON findmax.d = emp.startdate and findmax.name = emp.name
```

There are other ways of achieving the same thing without a join- this method would have issues if an employee was promoted twice on the same day, two records would result. In a dB that supports analytical functions we an do:

```
SELECT name, jobrole, row_number() over (partition by name order by startdate desc)
FROM emp
```

This establishes an incrementing  counter in order of descending start date. The counter restarts from 1 for every different employee. There is no group by so no complaints that the extra data isn’t grouped or on aggregate function. All we need to do to choose the most recent promotion date is wrap the whole thing in a select that demands the row number be 1:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT name, jobrole, row_number() over (partition by name order by startdate desc) r
  FROM emp
) emp_with_rownum
WHERE r = 1
```

Comment: This is what exactly happened. I accept happily this as solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `group by`.  You seem to want a window function:

```
select t.*, max(col) over () as overall_max
from t;
```

Comment: I need to check this as well.